# How can I merge textures from multiple materials into one?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, uv

I have two objects that I want to merge. They have different materials. Both were unwrapped and textured separately. When I join the meshes, it makes a single object with two materials. I wish to have a single material with a single UV map. Is there a way to do this without completely re-doing the texturing process?

I tried baking a new texture, but since they have different materials it didn't work the way I wanted. Any help is appreciated.

I'm using Cycles rendering.

Comment: What's the purpose of your model? If it's a game asset you want to use Blender internal and the Texture Atlas add-on later on in the process anyway.

Comment: It is a game asset. I don't think I know what you just said. Is it a complex thing?